# How to reset user password using RestAPI in Salesforce application?

Tags: java, api, salesforce

I have Salesforce admin credentials and password reset query.  I want to reset user password using Rest API. How to reset user password using RestAPI in Salesforce application ?  What is the password reset endpoint ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Users are treated as an sObject, so its the data api, so you access it at 
`https://<instance>.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/User/<UserId>`

and the password is at 
`https://<instance>.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/User/<UserId>/password`

To change a password using Curl
Create a file with contents like these (it must be valid json), and save it somewhere.

`{
    "NewPassword" : "myNewPassword1234"
}`

then post to the service using a curl command like (fill in yourInstance, UserId, yourOAuthToken, and yourPasswdFile):

`curl https://<yourInstance>.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/User/<UserId>/password -H "Authorization: Bearer <yourOAuthToken>" —H "Content-Type: application/json" —d @<yourPasswdFile>.json —X POST`

Theres more information and sample curl commands at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_user_password.htm#!

Comment: Thank you Frank Thomas